# DRY, how to avoid repeat methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing this in my class

```
Salesforce::Adapters::Person::MAPPINGS.invert.keys.each do |key|
  delegate key.to_sym,
         "#{key}=".to_sym,
         to: :person, 
         prefix: true
end

Salesforce::Adapters::EmergencyContact::MAPPINGS.invert.keys.each do |key|
    delegate key.to_sym,
         "#{key}=".to_sym,
         to: :emergency_contact, 
         prefix: true
end
```

I want to DRY, any idea how can I do it? I was trying to iterate inside the classes of the module but no success.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code, and belongs on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1):

You can try `const_get`:

```
def dry_class module, type
  Object.const_get("Salesforce::Adapters::#{module}")::MAPPINGS.invert.keys.each do |key|
    delegate key.to_sym,
    "#{key}=".to_sym,
    to: type, 
    prefix: true
  end
end
```